# Setting and Retrieving Dates in iOS that avoid issues with timezone changes

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate

I have a **"time-tracking"** app that allows a user to create an entry on whichever days a user desires but only one permitted per day. I store these entries into `CoreData`.

```
[rateObject setValue:[Day dateWithHour:currentDate forHour:12] forKey:@"date"];
```

Later, I retrieve these entries using the following code.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Day"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whoWorked == %@ && date => %@ && date =< %@", whoWorked, [Day dateWithHour:fromDate forHour:0], [Day dateWithHour:toDate forHour:24]];
```

As you can see I placed the entry in the middle of the day (12 hours) and retrieved the dates from start of the first day (0 hours) and end of the last day (24 hours).

This is a hack which seems to work when I only shift **timezones** by a few hours or switch for **Standard Time** to **Daylight Savings**. It falls apart when I  move from NA to Europe i.e. the entries in the old timezone appear on different days in the retrieval.

What I want to get to is an entry made on April 25, 2014 appears on April 25, 2014 no matter what **timezone** I am currently in.

I have looked at a number of sources to understand `NSDate`, `NSDateComponents`, `NSCalendar` etc but can't seem to land on a good understanding that will allow me to implement this correctly or cleanly. Any advice appreciated.

Here is my method for creating a date with a specific hour (in Day).

```
+ (NSDate *)dateWithHour:(NSDate *)date forHour:(int)hour {

// Create and initialize date component instance
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

if (hour<0) hour = 0;
else if (hour>24) hour = 24;

[dateComponents setHour:hour];

// Create period dates
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

return newDate;
```

}

Comment: All `NSDate` instances are referenced to GMT. The display is referenced to the users location or a specified timezone. The same applies to parsing text dates into `NSDate`. Keep in mind that April 25, 2014 is not the same for all users.

Comment: If you're really only interested in dates, I'd suggest just storing a string (or integer really) with the format "YYYYMMDD"  That way the sort, compare, etc. just as you'd expect, and you avoid the timezone issues.

Comment: What I see when I print out the date/time of my entries is that the 12 pm shifts around depending on what my current timezone is and the timezone that I made the entry. For example, if I made the entry in MST and print it out in MST it is 12 pm. However, if I made the entry in PST then review it in MST it appears as 1 PM.

Comment: Zaph - For my app I believe that I need an entry made on April 25, 2014 12 PM in Europe to appear as April 25 12 PM in MST. Otherwise when I do operations on entries that were made in a different timezone (when the delta time is large) I run the risk of having the entries appear in the wrong days. David's solution would work. However, when I started down the NSDate path it was based on advice to use NSDates for dates so as to not box myself into a limited implementation even though at this point it is difficult. Now, I am committed to making NSDate work if at least for my own understanding.

Comment: As I read everyone's thoughts I am wondering if I should force the timezone to GMT when I create and retrieve the entries with something like the [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]; to avoid the local timezone adjusting the times of both the entry and the retrieval limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best to use time-zone and platform independent is the timestamp, which you can get from `NSDate` as well. With that you can easily do calculations with Time-intervals. If you want to have a specific date it is always related to the time zone of the user. Then you can convert the timestamp into a user-formatted date. Like mentioned by Zaph he might want to see the date where he currently is. Again with the timestamp this is always reliable.

If you want to calculate that an entry can be done only once per calendar day in the location where somebody is, then you can calculate with ˙NSCalendar˙ and ˙NSDateComponents˙ for example what day a timestamp represents and then from the beginning of that day calculate 24 hours up. Conversion back to a timestamp gives you a helpful range for check if something is within the same calendar day. The `NSCalendar` is the base for calculation even if you will probably use Gregorian most of the time. With the `NSDateComponents`you can what ever part you want from your Timestamp (e. g. only the day, the month, the year, etc.).

Comment: Does my comments above impact this answer? My thought is using the NSDateComponents suffers from the same issue that the underlying date in the components will depend on the local timezone so when I shift timezones by over 12 hours what was in one day in my local timezone will be in a day before or after in the new timezone (depending on whether you are going east or west by 12+ hours).

Comment: To always use one Timezone or to use the timezone of the last entry is a possibility. The question is more what timeframe you want to use to limit the user. If you stick to one timezone, a user in another timezone will not understand your "day" limit because it will be a new day for him but maybe not for your default time zone. The third option is to limit in seconds from the last entry with 24 x 60 x 60 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll think through the implications to what I am trying to do.